# How To Parse .EML Files in Flutter

Tags: flutter, email, parsing, parse-platform, eml

I really need help, I couldn't find the solution. I have an eml file. I need to parse the contents of this file and use it to support eml files in my mail application, but I couldn't find a solution.

I can share my eml file content if you give me communication information.

I tried to use some parsing packages in flutter but without success. For example enough_mail. https://pub.dev/packages/enough_mail

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hey, did you find the solution? I want to access eml file content in my app

Comment: did it? @LuckyTrail

Comment: I used html package to show eml file and now it's working for me.